# How to exclude validation properties only on the mvc layer (and keep for database layer)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-web

I want to use the same bean for both database persistance, and for a webservice `json` request.

Problem: I have a property that should never be set by the webservice user, but filled by the application before persistance. The field in the db is marked as not null, so the domain validation is: `@NotNull`.

But if I add this, then spring-mvc will also validate the incoming json request and throw an exception if `id` is not set (but which is desired).

Question: how can I exclude certain validation properties only on the mvc layer?

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore //has no effect
    private String id; //to be set by application before persistance

    private String name;
    private int age;
}

@RestController 
public class PersonController {
    @PostMapping
    public void post(Person p) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need validation api on database ? Database constraints are not enough for you ?

Comment: When using model-first approach, `@NotNull` will trigger the column being set as "not nullable" during generation with hibernate. Eg if the application is deployed to a fresh environment.

Comment: `@Column(nullable=false)` and remove `@NotNull`

Comment: And what if I would want to use `@Null` for web layer validation? Then it's the other way around: I cannot exclude in for the domain layer.

Comment: I think you will need two different entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement you've described is to be able to define different constraints for the same bean depending on the respective context. In the MVC layer you want id to be nullable and persistence layer you want to it to be not-null.

You can implement this requirement by using [Validation Groups](http://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#validationapi-validatorapi-groups).

Your first introduce a new interface for the persistence validation case lets say:

```
public interface PersistenceGroup {

}
```

Then you change your bean to:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @NotNull(groups = PersistenceGroup.class)
    private String id; //to be set by application before persistance

    private String name;
    private int age;
}

@RestController 
public class PersonController {
    @PostMapping
    public void post(Person p) {

    }
}
```

This has the effect that *@NotNull* is only validated for the given group.Because by default the javax.validation.groups.Default group is used for validation, your MVC will not check for @NotNull. Now we tell Hibernate to use your group when its *BeanValidationEventListener* is activated in case of persisting, updating or deleting your entity. This can be done by setting the corresponding of the following properties (see [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-checkconstraints-orm-hibernateevent)):

- javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist
- javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update
- javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-remove

Example for your use case:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    ...
    <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist">
        javax.validation.groups.Default,your.package.PersistenceGroup
    </property>
    <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update">
        javax.validation.groups.Default,your.package.PersistenceGroup
    </property>
    ...
```